# Enable Disable SQL Server Agent Jobs

Tags: sql, jobs, agent

I have a script to disable all jobs and then another script to enable all jobs.  The problem I have is in some cases may be a few of the jobs have been manually disabled previously.  When it comes to re-enabling the jobs all jobs are enabled but in reality what we need is for those few manually disabled jobs to remain disabled.

Any ideas on how this might be achievable would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use msdb.dbo.sysjobs to assess last created or modified dates to filter for enable/disable.

```
select 
    sysjobs.name
    ,sysjobs.date_created
    ,sysjobs.date_modified
    ,max(sysjobactivity.run_requested_date)
from 
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs
inner join 
    msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity
on  
    sysjobs.job_id = sysjobactivity.job_id
group by 
    sysjobs.name
,sysjobs.date_created
    ,sysjobs.date_modified
order by
    sysjobs.name
    ,sysjobs.date_created
    ,sysjobs.date_modified
```

Comment: Thanks.  When the disable script is run all jobs are disabled so at this point the jobs that were disabled manually beforehand are not known.  So I need a step in the disable script that can log the jobs that are already disabled either in a table or text file.  When it comes to running the enable script which will enable all jobs I need a final step which will look at the table or text file to call the jobs that need disabling again.  make sense?

Comment: You should be able to filter further by name or by created/modified after, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, I've found that updating the sysjobs tables doesn't always work. An alternate solution could be to use a cursor. The following code would be handy for this situation -

```
DECLARE @currentjob VARCHAR(500)

DECLARE cursor_job_name CURSOR 
    FOR SELECT name
        FROM MSDB..sysjobs;

OPEN cursor_job_name;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_job_name INTO
    @currentjob;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC MSDB..sp_update_job @job_name = @currentjob, @enabled = 0;
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_job_name INTO
        @currentjob;
    END;

CLOSE cursor_job_name;

DEALLOCATE cursor_job_name;
```